# Adding a button to toolbar with jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to add a button to my toolbar of my [datatable](https://datatables.net/).
So, my [datatable](https://datatables.net/) is:

```
var dataTable =  $('#employee-grid').DataTable(
{
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: "employee-grid-data.php", // json datasource for AJAX Data

    "pagingType": "full_numbers",   //Adding Last and First in Pagination
    stateSave: true,
    "language":{                    //Custom Message Setting
                    "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page",    //Customizing menu Text
                    "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",             //Customizing zero record text - filtered
                    "info": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",           //Customizing showing record no
                    "infoEmpty": "No records available",                //Customizing zero record message - base
                    "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"   //Customizing filtered message
                },
    "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],        //For customizing number of data sets per page

});
```

And what I have done is like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var dataTable =  $('#employee-grid').DataTable(
        {
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "employee-grid-data.php", // json datasource for AJAX Data

            "pagingType": "full_numbers",   //Adding Last and First in Pagination
            stateSave: true,
            "language":{                    //Custom Message Setting
                            "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page",    //Customizing menu Text
                            "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",             //Customizing zero record text - filtered
                            "info": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",           //Customizing showing record no
                            "infoEmpty": "No records available",                //Customizing zero record message - base
                            "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"   //Customizing filtered message
                        },
            "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],        //For customizing number of data sets per page
            "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip'
        });

        $("div.toolbar").html('<button type="button" id="any_button">Click Me!</button>');
    } );
```

But I am finding something like this:

[image]

But I like to have something like this-

[image]

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Could you edit your question to point out what's different about the two screenshots?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

Use the code below:

*JavaScript*:

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   // ... skipped ...
   dom: 'l<"toolbar">frtip',
   initComplete: function(){
      $("div.toolbar")
         .html('<button type="button" id="any_button">Click Me!</button>');           
   }       
});
```

*CSS*:

```css
.toolbar {
    float:left;
}
```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oLugjLp8/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thank u very much friend :)

Comment: I'm surprised that I couldn't find the 'initComplete' event in the documentation though

Comment: Button appears but isn't clickable, had to modify the CSS to change `position` and `z-index`

Comment: If you using ajax this button will show after the data load. So instead of `initComplete` use `preDrawCallback`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use datatable button.js. Here is the source link:

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/custom.html

Don't forget to add below libraries (as mentioned in the above URL)

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can do also like below:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'My button',
                action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                    alert( 'Button activated' );
                }
            }
        ]
    } );
```

Source :https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/custom.html